# Duplicating a Jtree

Tags: java, tree

I need to create a copy of an already existing tree , created using DefaultMutableTreeNode.[Edit]
So, I have tried to assign the existing root node, to another DefaultMutableTreeNode.Ex:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode ABC = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(null);
DefaultMutableTreeNode ABCcopy = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(null);
ABCcopy=ABC;
```

But this didnt give me much results.
Please advice.

Comment: fixxxer, what have you tried so far?   Questions here seem to get answered best when the asker has written some code and needs specific help.

Comment: Edited the qn with a code sample.
Could you throw some light on "Use the built-in serialize mechanism to create deep clones" as commented by – nkr1pt

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to (deep) copy/clone an object in java is by serializing/deserializing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your both trees just for displaying some hierarchical data and do not modify nodes, so the easiest way is this:

```
JTree new_tree = new JTree(old_tree.getModel());
```

If you plan to modify one of trees the best way would be to clone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
ObjectOutputStream out = null;
try {
   fos = new FileOutputStream("somefilename");
   out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   out.writeObject(ABC);
   out.close();
} catch(IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}

FileInputStream fis = null;
ObjectInputStream in = null;
try {
   fis = new FileInputStream("somefilename");
   in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
   ABCCopy = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)in.readObject();
   in.close();
} catch(IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
} catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Lets suppose that a tree exists with the root node as ABC. How do we proceed with the above code, then? –

Comment: Exactly as in the example. Read it carefully, the out.writeObject(ABC) serializes the existing tree to the filesystem and ABCCopy = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)in.readObject() deserializes the tree into the ABCCopy variable. At that point you should have two identical trees.

Comment: What will be the contents of "somefilename"? Would any file format do?

Comment: yes never mind the content of "somefilename", it is not human-readable, I would just call it "temp".

Comment: also, bear in mind that the ObjectOutputStream accepts a ByteArrayOutputStream instead of a FileOutputStream. This eliminates the need for disk IO and thus for a filename to write to.
The same applies to the InputStreams

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
Tree newTree = existingTree.clone() ?
```

Comment: You need to cast: clone() returns an Object. Also, the OP should know that all objects inside his/her tree should implement the Cloneable interface.

Comment: seriously, save yourselves the trouble from implementing the Clonebale interface in the object graph of the objects you want to clone. Use the built-in serialize mechanism to create deep clones.